# extension of discrete groups

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Suppose $A$ and $C$ are discrete groups, $B$ is an extension of $C$ by $A$, i.e. we have a short exact sequence:

$1\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 1$
 Is $B$ also discrete?

Comment: The question makes no sense (or is tautologically true). It's like asking whether a set is a group. To make it meaningful, you need to assume that $B$ is a topological group and make some assumptions on the given maps (without assumptions on the maps, or even only assuming they're continuous, there are obvious counterexamples, e.g., $A=1$, $B=C$ as underlying groups with $B$ non-discrete).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Consider a convergent sequence $\{b_n\}_n$ in $B$. Then its image in $C$ converges, hence is eventually constant. Then for some $N\gg 0$, $b_nb_N^{-1}$ is in $A$ for all $n\gg 0$, where it still converges, hence is eventually constant.

Comment: I only know the fact that $G$ is a discrete group  if its topology is discrete. I find it difficult to show that all the subsets of $A$ is open. How to show that a group $G$ is discrete if the convergent sequence is eventually constant? In your proof, you mention that $B$ has a convergent sequence, does it must exist a convergent sequence in $B$?